# I want to change python3 command's path as default from anaconda path

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, conda, ubuntu-22.04

I have installed anaconda on my ubuntu 22.04.2LTS machine. But later, I have found out that anaconda's python module is not following the python standard rule. Thus, I have uninstalled anaconda by following it's official instruction but my python executing path was not restored to default python3 command's directory path.

When I try to run python3 command, it tries to run

> /home/(user name)/anaconda3/bin/python3

but not

> /usr/bin/python3

Maybe this can be because I have uninstalled anaconda without deactivation. But the anaconda has already uninstalled and removed from the machine, it seems path changing is not available. Is there anyway that I can restore the settings?

Comment: Maybe need to clean up your .bashrc or .bash_profile (remove conda sections)

Comment: Thanks for advice. I have checked them but there was nothing left over from conda. But fortunately, I found out that there was a back up directory in home directory and that was the problem.

Comment: `anaconda's python module is not following the python standard rule` can you elaborate?